# number to string representation

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm trying to make a function so that :

1 000 000 become 1m 
100 000 000 become 100m
999 000 000 become 999m
1 000 000 000 become 1b
100 000 000 000 become 100b
1000 000 000 000 become 1t

Doing some research on SO i've found a function that comes pretty close :

```
AbbreviateNumber = ({value}) => {
  var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
  var suffixNum = Math.floor((""+ Math.trunc(value)).length/3);
  var shortValue = parseFloat((suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum)) : 
value).toPrecision(2));
  if (shortValue % 1 != 0) {
      var shortNum = shortValue.toFixed(1);
  };
  return shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
};
```

The problem with that function is that :

`AbbreviateNumber(100000000000)` returns 0.1t instead of 100b.

I cannot find the proper logic so that it work for both 1 000 000 000 000 => 1t and 100 000 000 000 => 100b and not 0.1t or 100000 to return 100k and not 0.1m..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some simple way of doing it, but here's a literal method.

```
function abbrNum(num) {
  let mappings = {
    K: [1000, 999999],
    M: [1000000, 999999999],
    B: [1000000000, 999999999999],
    T: [1000000000000, 999999999999999],
  };

  let abs = Math.abs(num);

  for (var abbr in mappings) {
    if (abs >= mappings[abbr][0] && abs <= mappings[abbr][1]) {
      return Math.round(num / mappings[abbr][0])+abbr;
    }
  }

  return num;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6820medp/

Comment: (Math.abs(num) >= mappings[abbr][0] && Math.abs(num) <= mappings[abbr][1]) so that it works for negative numbers aswell

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit like dealing with currency, where you sometimes need to multiply by one hundred in order to remove the two decimal places used by most currencies, though in this case you just need to multiply your value by ten at the start, then divide by ten again near the end.

If you want to 'cheat', then you can adjust your `suffixNum` by one, but that wouldn't be very readable...